# How to add .htaccess {REQUEST_URI} at the end of this Rewrite Rule?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mod-proxy

Im making a site where users can create subdomains with files, folders etc.
these sites go into a folder called websites so it will be site.com/websites/subdomain.site.com
I only need to get {REQUEST_URI} at the end of the RewriteRule so that a user can go to
example, subdomain.site.com/images/etc/img.jpg and still their subdomain will be shown like subdomain.site.com/images/etc/img.jpg but the content will actually be on site.com/websites/subdomain.site.com/images/etc/img.jpg

Sorry for creating multiple questions, the docs is hard for me i'm totally new to this but im trying... please help with this :)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/websites/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /websites/%1/ [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Comment: Also if you can put it in a way that it can exclude www. as a subdomain that would be great!

Comment: can you rephrase your question title ?

Comment: You dont understand what im trying to say?

Comment: keep title simple please.

Comment: Anyone can help with this?

Comment: Hey Sivan can you tell one of your friends to help me out, its getting really late